# How to add virtual collection in viewmodel in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am new one in asp.net core world. I have created web project using asp.net core web application (.Net core)  vs 2017, I have already have database in sql server ,so I have changed as below

```
 "DefaultConnection": "data source=Fawaz\\sqlexpress;initial catalog=TaimorPoultryService;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

Build application and run it,it send me message to apply migration,I did clicked that button,then application start working,migration added new tables in my database as I have selected individual Authentication.

Now I want to create a view model CompanyViewModel with following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace FirstCoreApplication.Models.Department
{
    public class CompanyViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Company Name")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Company Contact")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string CompanyContact { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Created Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Select Department")]
        public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Problem is type Department highlighted with red line,but I have a table in my db with this name,how can I solve this problem that all the db entity should be visible in application like edm we did before using database first approach.

Comment: What is the error? (and not related, but it does not have to be `virtual`)

Comment: EF Core doesn't have lazy loading now, so there is no need to define properties as virtual.

Comment: Also you `namespace` looks odd (having `.Department` after `.Models`). And since its a view model, it should be in a separate folder so its not associated with EF. But view models should not contain properties which are data models anyway

Comment: Reference not found,are you missing assemble?

Comment: If I remove the Virtual still that red line is there?why does department is not being  referenced ?

Comment: I have also changed namespace department to just Depart,why EF does not give me option against missing reference so that I can add it?

Comment: What namespace is your `Department` class in? Add a using statement for it.

Comment: Like before when we use db first approach and generate model and using that reference we can get all the DBSET of database?

Comment: Its a view model! It has nothing to do with EF and should not have any relationship to it (and put you view models in a separate folder (say `ViewModels`) not in your `Models` folder)

Comment: I have changed it to new folder Named ViewModels, add a class named TPSCompany paste the code,if this model does not have relation with EF or  database generated class then like other field in my viewmodel that can work, but why it still not get <Department> ,and also if it is a type of collection then it must store somewher?in my case I am supposing to get it from db table named Department

Comment: I guess you need to create class named `Department` and configure Entity Framework to use it. Please read about [Creating a Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/).